# Как сверстать две колонки на CSS

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такое на CSS? мне приходит только `table` использовать, но мне кажется это не лучшая идея.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно использовать сетку и две колонки - левая с кнопкой и правая с четырьмя блоками.

Comment: Если поддержка браузеров позволяет, то можно использовать CSS Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .flex {
        flex-direction: column
    }  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="col-md-6">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 flex">
        <div class="col-md-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для наглядности можно фоны блоков сделать цветными, и использовать вставку кода в сниппет, что бы прямо на стаке запускался, следующая после картинки кнопка в редакторе.

Answer (score 0):

Подобные колонки можно сделать таким вот образом:

1. Сделать дивами и задать им `display: table;`
2. Сделать таблицами;
3. Применить `display: flex;`

Всё зависит от ваших целей и задач